# 3 IQ Test patterns - 3x3 grids of 3x3 grids with Xs, circles, squares, shading

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

I'm stuck on these questions and I don't really know why. The more I look at them, the more I get confused. I can't seem to get the pattern here. What pattern do you see and what do you believe to be the most logical answer?

1:
[image: Nr 1]

2:
[image: Nr 2]

3:
[image: Nr 3]

(Clickthrough to get full-sized images)

These questions are from an IQ test on [123test.com](https://www.123test.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.

> Row 2 Column 2: Rotate each grid by 90degrees clockwise vertically. The highlighted objects include one of each type and number 1,2,3 in every row and column.

2.

> Row 2 Column 1: The circle doesn't move across a row. The middle column provides an axis to reflect the first column into the third column with, extending in one direction to an edge.

3.

> Row 1 Column 2: There are three different grid patterns, arranged as:
>
> ```
>  A B C
>  B C A
>  C A B
> ```
>
> Each pattern has a different shape for 1, 2 and 3 objects in the grid.

Comment: Just beat me to it well done

Comment: Of course! well done!

Comment: That first one was too easy, but well done for getting the others! $(+1)$ :P

Comment: I disagree with the explanation on 2. 
The idea is that a line originating from the circle, is rotating around it (either clockwise or counter-clockwise). Rotation is 45 degrees.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson; nice!

Answer (score 0):

For the first picture, find the ones which have X, O, and Square. They must be either in same column or in the same row. In each row, look inside and check how many X, O, and Square is in a row or column. For the first row, there are only 2 X, O, and Square in a row and 1 as a column. We can now eliminate 1st, 4th, and 5th options.

Now search for 0, Square, and 0 for each row. It can be in a diagonal or column or row. For the 3rd, 6th, and 9th there is Square, 0, and Square in a row. So for the 1st and 2nd column, the rule is 0, Square, and 0 (can be in diagonal, row or column and for the 2nd and 3rd column, the rule gets reversed like this: Square, 0, Square. We may now eliminate the 2nd option! Now, let's see what options have lasted so far: 3rd, 6th and 7th.

To use the ones in colored with yellow, there is a simple rule: In each row, there should be 3 colored object in one part, 2 colored and 1 colored, and they have to be different. There are 3, 2, and 1 colored X's, 3, 2, and 1 colored squares but there are only 3 and 2 colored circles so we need only 1 colored circle in a square. So the answer is the 5th object.